# Integration Error stripe Invalid Value value should be a client secret string. You specified: undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I have a react project with nodejs server-side code with stripe implemented. I tested out the stripe code with a test card on my local machine and it worked fine, but when I uploaded it to firebase hosting and tried to test up there I received an error like this 'Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string. You specified: undefined'. So I figured nodejs cant be uploaded to firebase so I did cloud functions and I still get the same error. I thought it was because of how I was calling the rest of API with project location, project id, and function name in URL. Here is my server-side code.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.post("/", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, amount } = req.body;
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency: "usd",
    
      // Verify your integration in this guide by including this parameter
      metadata: { integration_check: "accept_a_payment" },
      receipt_email: email,
    });
    console.log(paymentIntent);
// return res.status(200).json({
//   confirm: "abc123"
// })
    res.status(200).send({ client_secret: paymentIntent["client_secret"] });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});


exports.pay = functions.https.onRequest(app);
// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("hello from jerry")
  console.log("Hello From Jerry");
});

// On sign up.
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // Check if user meets role criteria.
  if (user.email) {
    const customClaims = {
      active: true,
      accessLevel:"paid",
    };
    // Set custom user claims on this newly created user.
    return admin
      .auth()
      .setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims)
      .then(() => {
        // Update real-time database to notify client to force refresh.
        const metadataRef = admin.database().ref(user.uid);
        // Set the refresh time to the current UTC timestamp.
        // This will be captured on the client to force a token refresh.
        return metadataRef.set({ refreshTime: new Date().getTime() });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
});
```

Here is my react code

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
// MUI Components
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import access from "../../assets/icon-5.png";
import { useAuth } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import rocket from "../../assets/rocket.png";
import question from "../../assets/question-mark.png";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getProducts } from "../../actions/products";
import Spinner from "../Spinner/Spinner";
import moment from "moment";
import { setAlert } from "../../actions/alert";
import { useStripe, useElements, CardElement } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CardInput from "./CardInput";
import "./common.css";
import { Fragment } from "react";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    // maxWidth: 500,
  },
  content: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignContent: "flex-start",
  },
  div: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignContent: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  button: {
    margin: "2em auto 1em",
  },
});

const HomePage = ({ getProducts, products, location, setAlert }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { state } = location;
  console.log(state, "params");
  const { signup } = useAuth();

  const classes = useStyles();
  // State
  const [totalPlan, setPurchaseSummary] = useState({
    total: "19.99",
    planAccess: "",
    start: "",
    end: "",
  });
  const { total, planAccess, start, end } = totalPlan;
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [planList, setPlan] = useState({
    bronze: "",
    silver: "",
    gold: "",
    platinum: "",
    amount: 0,
  });
  const { bronze, silver, gold, platinum, amount } = planList;

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });
  const { email, customer, password, confirmPassword } = formData;
  const onChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  console.log(products, "products");

  let productArray = Object.values(products);
  let firstItemInProductArray = [];
  firstItemInProductArray = productArray[0];
  console.log(firstItemInProductArray);
  let onProductsArray = Object.values(firstItemInProductArray);
  console.log(onProductsArray);
  let holderArray = [];
  holderArray = holderArray.concat(onProductsArray);
  let secondProductArray = [];
  secondProductArray = holderArray[0];
  console.log(secondProductArray);
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return null;
    }

    const res = await axios.post("http://us-central-nbe-online-prep.cloudfunctions.net/pay", {
      email: email,
      amount,
    });

    const clientSecret = res.data["client_secret"];
    console.log(clientSecret);
    const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
      clientSecret,
      {
        payment_method: {
          type: "card",
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
          billing_details: {
            email: email,
          },
        },
      }
    );
    let results = {
      total,
      planAccess,
      start,
      end,
      customer,
    };

    try {
      if (!!results && paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
        await signup(email, password);
        history.replace({
          pathname: "/success",
          state: { result: results },
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setAlert(`${error.message}`, "danger");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, [setLoading]);

  const selectProduct = (plan) => {
    switch (plan) {
      case "bronze":
        console.log("bronze");
        setPlan((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          bronze: "bronze",
          silver: "",
          gold: "",
          platinum: "",
          amount: 1999,
        }));

        setPurchaseSummary((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          total: "19.99",
          planAccess: "Bronze",
          start: moment().format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"),
          end: moment().add(30, "days").format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"),
        }));
        break;
      case "silver":
        console.log("silver");
        setPlan((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          bronze: "",
          silver: "silver",
          gold: "",
          platinum: "",
          amount: 3999,
        }));
        setPurchaseSummary((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          total: "39.99",
          planAccess: "Silver",
          start: moment().format(),
          end: moment().add(1, "months"),
        }));
        break;
      case "gold":
        console.log("gold");
        setPlan((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          bronze: "",
          silver: "",
          gold: "gold",
          platinum: "",
          amount: 6999,
        }));
        setPurchaseSummary((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          total: "69.99",
          planAccess: "Gold",
          start: moment().format(),
          end: moment().add(3, "months"),
        }));
        break;
      case "platinum":
        console.log("platinum");
        setPlan((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          bronze: "",
          silver: "",
          gold: "",
          platinum: "platinum",
          amount: 11999,
        }));
        setPurchaseSummary((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          total: "119.99",
          planAccess: "Platinum",
          start: moment().format(),
          end: moment().add(12, "months"),
        }));
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="container">
      {!loading && stripe ? (
        <Fragment>
          <div className="grid-pay">
            <div className="start">
              <h1 style={{ color: "#000000", textAlign: "justify" }}>
                Start Learning Today
              </h1>
              <p style={{ textAlign: "justify" }}>
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
                by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
                The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
                normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
                here, content here', making it look like readable English.
              </p>
              <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                <ul style={{ textAlign: "justify" }}>
                  <li style={{ color: "#000000" }}>
                    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          alt="lock"
                          src={question}
                          style={{ width: 60, height: 60, marginBottom: 20 }}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <p style={{ marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 10 }}>
                          Unlimited access to all courses
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li style={{ color: "#000000" }}>
                    {" "}
                    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          alt="rocket icon"
                          src={rocket}
                          style={{ width: 60, height: 60, marginBottom: 20 }}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <p style={{ marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 10 }}>
                          Hands-on exercises
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li style={{ color: "#000000" }}>
                    {" "}
                    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          alt="lock"
                          src={access}
                          style={{ width: 60, height: 60, marginBottom: 20 }}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div style={{ marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 10 }}>
                        <p>Weekly additions and updates</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
                <Card className={classes.root}>
                  <div>
                    <p
                      style={{
                        color: "#000000",
                        fontSize: 30,
                        textAlign: "justify",
                        marginLeft: 20,
                        marginTop: 20,
                      }}
                    >
                      Choose Your Plan
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="button-grid" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                    <div
                      onClick={() => selectProduct("bronze")}
                      id={`${bronze}`}
                      className={`gray `}
                      style={{ paddingTop: 5 }}
                    >
                      <h3>$19.99</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      onClick={() => selectProduct("silver")}
                      id={`${silver}`}
                      className={`gray `}
                      style={{ paddingTop: 5 }}
                    >
                      <h3>$39.99</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      onClick={() => selectProduct("gold")}
                      id={`${gold}`}
                      className={`gray`}
                      style={{ paddingTop: 5 }}
                    >
                      <h3>$69.99</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      onClick={() => selectProduct("platinum")}
                      id={`${platinum}`}
                      className={`gray`}
                      style={{ paddingTop: 5 }}
                    >
                      <h3>$119.99</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <CardContent className={classes.content}>
                    <TextField
                      label="Name"
                      id="outlined-email-input"
                      helperText={`Enter full name`}
                      margin="normal"
                      variant="outlined"
                      type="text"
                      required
                      name="customer"
                      value={customer}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                      fullWidth
                    />
                    <TextField
                      label="Email"
                      id="outlined-email-input"
                      helperText={`Email you'll recive updates and receipts on`}
                      margin="normal"
                      variant="outlined"
                      type="email"
                      required
                      name="email"
                      value={email}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                      fullWidth
                    />
                    <TextField
                      label="Passwod"
                      id="outlined-password-input"
                      helperText={`Create Password for your account`}
                      margin="normal"
                      variant="outlined"
                      type="password"
                      required
                      name="password"
                      value={password}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                      fullWidth
                    />
                    <TextField
                      label="confirm password"
                      id="outlined-password-input"
                      helperText={`Confirm Password`}
                      margin="normal"
                      variant="outlined"
                      type="password"
                      required
                      name="confirmPassword"
                      value={confirmPassword}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                      fullWidth
                    />
                    <div
                      style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                      }}
                    >
                      <div>
                        <h3>Amount</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <p style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: 22 }}>${total}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
                      <CardInput />
                    </div>
                  </CardContent>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      marginTop: 50,
                      marginLeft: 10,
                      marginRight: 10,
                      marginBottom: 30,
                    }}
                  >
                    <input
                      style={{}}
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn-style-two btn-primary button-gradient"
                      value="Purchase"
                    />
                  </div>
                </Card>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      ) : (
        <Spinner />
      )}
    </section>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.products,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts, setAlert })(HomePage);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong I would appreciate the help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your front end code is set up to call "http://us-central-nbe-online-prep.cloudfunctions.net/pay", whereas the route you defined that creates the PaymentIntent is "/".

Your server route likely needs to be changed to `"/pay"` for it to work.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Just leave the route to be "/" and it worked fine